# How to examine items in a "set" without a cons operator

Tags: sml, ml, abstract-data-type

This is one example of code that I would imagine work work fine in a set data type implemented as a list:

```
fun newSet() = nilset;

fun isMember (k, x::xs) = if k = x then true else isMember (k, xs)
  | isMember (k, nilset) = false;
```

The problem is that I cannot implement it as a list.  Below is the code for the implementation of my set.

```
abstype ''a set = nilset | st of ''a * ''a set
```

How can I recursively do this and other set operations if `::` is for lists?  If it's not, why is this throwing exceptions?  I get this when I use `::`:

```
! Type clash: pattern of type
!   ''a set
! cannot have type
!   ''b list
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't an exception; it is a type error saying that you can't use cons constructor `::` belonging to `'a list` with `'a set`.

Assuming that you have two constructors `Nilset` and `Set` in a recursive datatype:

```
datatype 'a set = Nilset | Set of 'a * 'a set
```

You should follow the recursive structure of your datatype to define `isMember`:

```
fun isMember (k, Set(x, xs)) = k = x orelse isMember (k, xs)
  | isMember (k, Nilset) = false
```

Certainly, for serious use of `Set`, you should look into [Set structure](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2007fa/recitations/rec09.html).

Comment: ok, thank you.  I've never coded in ML before.  I've got a little background in Java, but I'm hoping to expand that.  Much appreciated!

Comment: I added a complete example. Hope that help you to get started.